# Spring Oauth2 Error "Token not found in request parameters" on entering username and password in custom login page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I have created custom login page in spring boot and spring-security-oauth2. On entering username and password getting error as

o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
s.s.o.p.e.DefaultOAuth2ExceptionRenderer : Written [error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"] as "application/xhtml+xml" using [org.springframework.security.oauth2.http.converter.jaxb.JaxbOAuth2ExceptionMessageConverter@cefdf9]

How to pass token as header parameter any lead?

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Import(Encoders.class)
    public class ServerSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder userPasswordEncoder;

        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(userPasswordEncoder);
        }

        @Override
        @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/about").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginSecure")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/index", true)
            .permitAll();
            }
}
```

and ResourceServer

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource-server-rest-api";
        private static final String SECURED_READ_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('read')";
        private static final String SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE = "#oauth2.hasScope('write')";
        private static final String SECURED_PATTERN = "/secured/**";

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
        }

        @Override
        @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login", "/resources/**/**","/resources/").permitAll()
            .and().requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/loginSecure", SECURED_PATTERN).and().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/loginSecure", SECURED_PATTERN).access(SECURED_WRITE_SCOPE)
                    .anyRequest().access(SECURED_READ_SCOPE)
                    .and().csrf().disable();

        }
}
```

AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter  class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Import(ServerSecurityConfig.class)
public class AuthServerOAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder oauthClientPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler oauthAccessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").passwordEncoder(oauthClientPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).authenticationManager(authenticationManager).userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your spring security configuration ?

Comment: @chaoluo thank you for your time. I have added the configuration classes.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem after changing the order of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter higher than the resource server.
This is because of resource server's filterChains ranks higher than the one by WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configured filterchain.

reference link: 
  [Spring security with Oauth2 or Http-Basic authentication for the same resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526644/spring-security-with-oauth2-or-http-basic-authentication-for-the-same-resource)